# svnadmin load fails with "Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service"

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svn-administraton

Someone committed a file to the subversion repository that must be removed.

The server is a virtualized Windows Server 2003 32-bit box with 4GB RAM and plenty of disk space where the repositories reside. We're using SVN 1.4.4.

The dump file was around 90GB, and roughly the same size filtered.

The load of the filtered dump failed with "Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service." This happened after roughly 99% of the filtered dump was loaded (r9945/9991). I tried again and it failed earlier (~r7.5k).

There are tons of hits on this particular error, but they seem to deal with source code and buffer errors. I need some way to remove this file and restore the repository. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I forgot to add that I had task manager up while performing the operations and the CPUs aren't pegging and RAM usage never gets above ~2.1GB.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by copying the filtered dump to my local machine and using the latest Subversion release (1.8.10) to perform the following...

```
svnadmin create new_repo --pre-1.5-compatible --compatible-version 1.4.4
svnadmin load new_rep < filtered-dump
```